# Disable Google Analytics when in development

Tags: android, google-analytics

My question is pretty simple: is there any way for Google Analytics to be disabled automatically when the application is signed with the debug certificate? Means it should be active only in release version. Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable GoogleAnalytics from Android App when testing or developing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314357/disable-googleanalytics-from-android-app-when-testing-or-developing)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using ADT 17 and above, you can utilize the BuildConfig class:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    GoogleAnalytics googleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    googleAnalytics.setAppOptOut(true);
}
```

The `BuildConfig` class is automatically generated like `R.java` is. It only contains the `DEBUG` boolean, which is set to `true` by default, and to `false` when you export an apk.

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept your answer. But I thought Google Analytics could have some kind of configuration APIs that allow you to set this kind of rules.

Comment: I don't think it does, but I may be wrong. I'm not very familiar with GA itself.

Comment: Beware, BuildConfig.DEBUG seems to be buggy : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940

Comment: @RaghavSood I think the preferred way of doing this has changed since you posted your answer... it looks like it's encouraged to use `GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).setDryRun(true))` instead for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can set it to not be active easily enough:

```
if (...) {
  GoogleAnalytics ga= GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
  ga.setAppOptOut(true);
}
```

I usually just check the hardware serial number of some known devices used for testing:

```
if (Arrays.asList("x", "y").contains(getHardwareSerial()))
```

Where `getHardwareSerial()` is:

```
public static String getHardwareSerial() {
        try {
            Field serialField = Build.class.getDeclaredField("SERIAL");
            return (String) serialField.get(null);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsf) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ia) {
        }
        return Build.UNKNOWN;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of Google Analytics, you should be using the following code:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setDryRun(true);
}
```