# Rails.env equivalent for Android

Tags: android, runtime, development-environment, production-environment

Is there an equivalent for `Rails.env` in Android or some other way to determine in runtime if the current code is running in a development, testing or production environment?

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse or Ant, your project contains a `BuildConfig` class, code-generated into your application's package (i.e., the same package that has your `R`, the one from the `package` attribute of the `<manifest>` element). This contains a public static data member, `DEBUG`, which will be `true` or `false` based upon whether you did a debug or production build. There is no concept here of "testing".

The [new Gradle-based build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), currently under development, will give you much more flexibility here.

Comment: BuildConfig is very unreliable, check https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940 
and
http://www.digipom.com/be-careful-with-buildconfig-debug/
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855834/when-does-adt-set-buildconfig-debug-to-false