# How to differentiate between release and debug builds if you can't rely on BuildConfig.DEBUG

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

How do you differentiate between release and debug builds in your Android development taking into consideration you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176284/buildconfig-debug-always-false-when-building-library-projects-with-gradle) [rely](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962) on `BuildConfig.DEBUG` flag?

I'm using Android Studio with Gradle and prefer to produce release/debug builds using Gradle tasks, I also need it to produce those on TeamCity.

For example, I need to use different `String` values for release and debug. What I'm going to do is to store them in `main` and `debug` folders separately so the proper one is picked up depending on the build. This is kind of okay, but what if I need to have a `flag` in `if/else` to decide which way to go?

Comment: What about `BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE`?

Answer (score 0):

add in your `build.gradle` a suffix to debug versions

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        buildTypes {
            debug {
               versionNameSuffix = "-DEBUG"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then on runtime you check the version name:

```
     PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
     mBuildVersion = pInfo.versionName;
     if(mBuildVersion.contains("DEBUG")){
          // DEBUG
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your application is debuggable by something like this

```
boolean isDebuggable = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code only answers. There is no explanation of what this code does and as such your answer is potentially liable to removal.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if obfuscation has been made:

```
package com.example.customandroid;

public abstract class DebugBuildChecker {
    public static boolean isDebugBuild() {
        //Log.d("~~~","class="+DebugBuildChecker.class.getName());
        return DebugBuildChecker.class.getName().endsWith(".DebugBuildChecker");
    }
}
```

After obfuscation, the class name will be something like `com.example.a.a` and the function will return false. Of course, one can tell proguard to keep the name of this class; just don't do it, and the check will work.