# BuildConfig.DEBUG always return false

Tags: android, android-log

Why does `BuildConfig.DEBUG` return false, when I run the application?

I use it to control the log like the following:

```
public static void d(String LOG_TAG, String msg){
    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BuildConfig.DEBUG always false when building library projects with gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176284/buildconfig-debug-always-false-when-building-library-projects-with-gradle)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your Android Studio **build variant** are you on **debug** variant?

That is applied when you use `flavors`, either for `debug` or `release`.

in the debug mode, `BuildConfig.BUILD` is true, and in the release mode, it is false.

Comment: How does this work if I have a dev variant next to debug, and I want them both to be debuggable? Adding debuggable=true to dev variant did not help.

Answer (score 113):

Check imports in the class, make sure you are using correct BuildConfig path. You may use BuildConfig not from your app, but from some library.

Comment: Yes.  You want `import com.myurl.mypackage.BuildConfig`, not the compat or any other Android or library versions.

Comment: I had imported Timber's BuildConfig. Bye bye 20 mins :)

Comment: This simple single-paragraph answer is underrated.

Comment: For React Native you need to be extra careful not to import `import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;` , make sure to import your own BuildConfig! Otherwise your Dev menu will never appear when you shake your device

Answer (score 9):

Ensure the auto import statement of build config on the top of your class belongs to your project.

```
com.your.package.name.BuildConfig
```

the `BuildConfig` import might belong to a released library there `DEBUG` is false.

Answer (score 7):

If that code is in a library, then it'll always be false, thanks to a [3-year-old bug in gradle](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962).

Comment: This was fixed in 2017 :-) (AGP 3.0)

Answer (score 7):

Do not import `BuildConfig`. This is an auto-generated class and importing it is unnecessary, despite what Android Studio may tell you.

If Android Studio is prompting you to import `BuildConfig` it may be because you need to do an initial Gradle build to create the auto-generated class which ends up being created at `com.yourdomain.yourapp.BuildConfig`. This can happen when you upgrade Android Studio and Gradle, or when you run <kbd>Build -> Clean project</kbd>.

If you import another package's `BuildConfig`, then of course it'll always be false because they are only releasing their release flavours and not their debug flavours.

Regarding the other answers recommending modifying your `build.gradle`, I found that specifying `buildType` conflicted with the default behaviour of Android Studio and its generation of `BuildConfig`, stating I had a duplicate entry.

So essentially:

- Do not import any package's `BuildConfig` (so let it stay red)
- Do not add `buildType` to your `build.gradle` (this may conflict with the default build behaviour of auto-generating the class)
- Ignore the lint error
- Run build

The error should go away.

I experience this when I upgrade Android Studio and Gradle and when I clean the project.

**Ignore import prompts**

Do not import another package's `BuildConfig`—it'll always be false because they are not releasing their debug versions.

[image]

**Importing will cause the error you're experiencing**

In my project, if I import one of the suggested libraries, it'll show the error you're getting, because no one releases a debug build so of course it'll always be false if you're pointing to someone else's.

[image]

[image]

**Ignore the intellisense and run the project**

Just run a build. The class will be auto-generated and the warning will go away.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not ideal, but I ended up creating my own

```
    buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG", "true" // Had issues with BuildConfig.DEBUG, created IS_DEBUG to ensure functionality behaved as expected.
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUG", "false"
    }
}
```

And then address it like `BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG` programatically.

Comment: This is a manual setting. Instead, use the usual one because the value of `BuildConfig.DEBUG` changes, when you switch from `debug` mode to `release`. But thanks, you have given the idea of creating constants at BuildConfig level.

Comment: In order to make your `BuildConfig` based constants semi-dynamic, you should use flavors. But this is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 4):

I specified `debuggable true` in build.config, but this is **always** false

After this change (simply remove it), all was working properly :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround for the problem:

**App**

```
dependencies {
    releaseCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'release')
    debugCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'debug')
}
```

**Library**

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for me, at least if you have that problem with a module / library. And this is not a workaround, you overwrite the default Android behavior for libraries, because you own this library.

Comment: One should use flavors to manage the release time and debug time settings.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are importing the wrong package, check that. (some Android libraries also have the BuildConfig class)