# Issue with Android Emulator no longer connecting to package server

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

After installing and configuring the `react-native-firebase` package for my app, running `react-native run-android` no longer creates a `index.android.bundle` file. I've been able to work around this by running the following command:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android`

However, I now need to run this command every time I make a change to the javascript in my app because the app no longer attempts to connect to the Metro Bundler. I can also not force it to connect by hitting `R R` and no errors are displayed. The app does launch correctly, just with this large caveat.

I'm not sure where to look here, I'm not an Android/Java Dev. I am on React-Native version 0.59.5

`android/build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        // ADD THIS
        maven { 
            url 'https://maven.google.com' 
        }

        // ADD THIS
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

`android/app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'file.icomoon.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.CLIENTNAME"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-haptic-feedback')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-video')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm not really sure if there are any other files to place here that could provide context. Please let me know if I'm missing any info here.

I'm expecting that when I run `react-native run-android` the bundler will run and create the `android/app/src/main/res/index.android.bundle` file that the app needs to run and that the app will connect to Metro Bundler from the Emulator. This allows me to be able to easily view changes to my JS code in the emulator. There are no error messages to speak of.

Answer (score 2):

In your `MainApplication.java` class, check the method

```
@Override
public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
}
```

it might be happening that `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is always returning `false`, so make sure the import package for `BuildConfig` is from your project, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61078792/399459), if you imported `BuildConfig` by mistake from a different package, the `BuildConfig` import might belong to a released library where `DEBUG` is `false`.

Also, check this answer on this issue 
[Could not connect to development server on android emulator and on real device #15388](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15388#issuecomment-559555391)
.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the packager using `npm start reset --cache`

Also upgrade to recent react native cli and use jetifiers and npx if targeting android X

Comment: I appreciate the response. I have tried all of these solutions without luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Do one thing. 1. Delete the node modules folder. 2. Delete the package lock.JSON folder 3. upgrade all the dev dependies `  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",` 4.Downgrade react native CLI to 1.0.2 if react native version is less then 0.60 else upgrade it to 2.0+. Let me know the conclusion

Comment: Also adding to my answer is that if you do npm start --reset cache from terminal and then run the emulator and then refresh it. It should start it. Also see the port is 8081

Comment: I just did the following:
1. Deleted `node_modules`
2. Deleted `package-lock.json`
3. upgraded all dependencies
4. set `metro-react-native-babel-preset`: to `^0.53.1`
5. Downgraded to react-native-cli `1.3.0` since that was the most recent v1 release
6. `react-native start --reset-cache`
7. Opened Android Emulator
8. Ran `react-native run-android` 

Still no bundle was created.