# react native run-android live reload not working

Tags: android, react-native

When I use `npx react-native run-android` command to run my project on android the live reload feature doesn't work and I can't even bring up the developer menu using Command + M.

When I run the same project on iOS using `npx react-native run-ios` everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using MacOS 10.15.5 and React native 0.62.2. Not using Expo.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you might not be doing anything wrong - sometimes I see an edit I've made breaks reloading.  Just have to rerun the NPX... command to get it restarting and it will work again for a while

Comment: I've tired rerunning it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Were you able to figure out your issue? just curious about solution.

Comment: Just found out that changing `getUseDeveloperSupport()` method in MainApplication.java to `return true` instead of `return BuildConfig.DEBUG` fixes the issue. 

This is just a work around.

Comment: @CodeHat thnxx it's working by your trick

Comment: @Asma_Kh glad i could help and thanks for letting me know. Please up vote the answers so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this. There were two issues with my project. Firstly `BuildConfig` was being imported from react in my `MainApplication.java` file. According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183752/9295598 it should come from my package. Once I resolved this I noticed that my package name didn't match my folder structure. Seem like I renamed my project in the past and didn't update the folder structure.

Once the folder structure was fixed and `BuildConfig` was imported from my project, the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` started working as intended which fixed the rest of the issues.