# BuildConfigField boolean is always false in library project

Tags: android, gradle

I am building a library in Android Studio and wish to have a `BuildConfigField` boolean, called `performance`, set to true for performance builds. However, it returns false and I need to fix it.

I followed the normal steps to create the field. My issue arises when `performance` is set to true in `BuildConfig.java`, but the Java code executes as if it were false. The library build variant is `performance` and app variant is `debug`.

Below is Java code which evaluates `performance` as false, inside a library file. Furthermore, `"BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE"` returns `"debug"`.

```
    if (BuildConfig.performance) {
        // do the thing
    }
```

The `build.gradle` file for the library

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {}
        debug {}
        performance {}

        // set "performance = true" for performance build type
        libraryVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                if (variant.getName().contains("performance")) {
                    variant.buildConfigField "Boolean", "performance", "true"
                } else {
                    variant.buildConfigField "Boolean", "performance", "false"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

From another SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29163361/2337925), I have tried the following without success

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your build variants, specify the fields:

```
  release {
      ...
      buildConfigField "Boolean", "performance", "false"
  }
  performance {
      ...
      buildConfigField "Boolean", "performance", "true"
  }
```

Comment: This does not work. BuildConfig.java shows `public static final Boolean performance = true;` however it is not evaluated and logged as such.

Comment: @clever_trevor what do you mean it is not evaluated as such??

Comment: The value of `performance` is true inside BuildConfig.java, however when I walk through the code, it is treated as false and does not execute the block inside the if-statement above. I logged `performance` and it's false as well.

Comment: Did you remove your `libraryVariants.all` block? You have the field in the class as you wanted. Sure you are not changing it elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, I copied your solution and no luck. The field is only used in the lines above. If I move the `"true"` line to debug and change the build variant to debug, then field evaluates correctly. However, I need a separate build variant. Do you think the issue has to do with using a debug variant for the app and performance variant for the library?

Comment: What do mean with "far from ideal"? Did you specify the field for all your build types? I solved your question, your problem seems to be your own logic...