# How can I use different settings when debugging an android app?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have an android app that uses a certain url to communicate with our server when used in production. I want to be able to use a different url when I am debugging, so that I can run the app against a local instance of the server on my machine.

How can I do this without manually editing the url?

Comment: Why did the 2 answers that got downvoted get downvoted?

Comment: @zgc7009 my guess is that it was because they don't address the underlying issue - without manually editing - which implies some dynamic logic, which those 'answers' do not address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Android Studio, you can define build variants, and define strings in that case:

### Generate Java Constants

**Plugin version greater than 0.7.x (current method)**

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "int", "FOO", "42"
            buildConfigField "String", "FOO_STRING", "\"foo\""
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField "int", "FOO", "52"
            buildConfigField "String", "FOO_STRING", "\"bar\""
        }
    }
}
```

**Plugin version less than 0.7 (old)**

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfig "public final static int FOO = 42;"
        }

        release {
            buildConfig "public final static int FOO = 52;"
        }
    }
}
```

You can access them with `BuildConfig.FOO`

### Generate Android resources (since plugin 0.8.3)

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug{
            resValue "string", "app_name", "My App Name Debug"
        }
        release {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "My App Name"
        }
    }
}
```

You can access them in the usual way with `@string/app_name` or `R.string.app_name`

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201265/1096905 (All credits to him, i just copy&paste)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Development Tools for Eclipse, look into BuildConfig.DEBUG. There is some discussion of it at [When does ADT set BuildConfig.DEBUG to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855834/when-does-adt-set-buildconfig-debug-to-false)

Answer (score -1):

You could make a utility class that generates urls for you. Extending on what Robin Ellerkmann mentioned before me.

```
public class UrlGenerator{

    private static final String STAGIN_URL = "http://www.statingurl.com/";
    private static final String PRDOUCTION_URL = "http://www.productionurl.com/";

    private static final boolean DEBUGGING = true;

    private static String getBaseUrl(){
        if(DEBUGGING)
            return STAGING_URL;
        else
            return PRODUCTION_URL;
    }

    public static String getLoginUrl(){
        return getBaseUrl() + "login";
    }
}
```

And then throughout your app something like

```
String loginRequestUrl = UrlGenerator.getLoginUrl();
```

That way it is all managed in your utility class.

Answer (score -2):

Use a global DEBUGGING boolean variable and if/else statements in your code.

```
private boolean DEBUGGING = true;

if (DEBUGGING) {
    //Use local machine url here
} else {
    //Use real url here
}
```