# android gradle flavors in the last Android studio

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I would like to create two falvors for my project. I did this successfully in the past but with new ANdroidStudio I a little bit concerned how to do that. The official guide is out-dated.

In the past what we need to do is to create additional folders on the level of "src" folder. In the current version of AndroidStudio we have app->{/java;/manifests;/res} structure and we can create folder only under the same package and I don't see the way to create additional folder for "res"

Can you advise please how I can create flavors for my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The official guide is out-dated.

The core of [the official guide's section on product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) seems fine to me.

> In the past what we need to do is to create additional folders on the level of "src" folder.

That would define a sourceset for a product flavor. You still need to declare the product flavor in `build.gradle` for the module, via a `productFlavors` closure or via the Project Structure dialog.

> In the current version of AndroidStudio we have app->{/java;/manifests;/res} structure

Switch from the Android view of your project contents to the Project view, via the drop-down just above the project structure tree.

You will start with a tree like:

[image: Android Studio project, Android view]

and change it to a tree like:

[image: Android Studio project, Project view]

> Can you advise please how I can create flavors for my app?

Add a `productFlavors` closure to your module's `build.gradle` file, manually or via the Project Structure dialog:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        vanilla {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

If you want to have alternative source for that product flavor (Java, resources, manifest, etc.), create `src/.../` in the project, where `...` is the name of your flavor (`src/vanilla/` would correspond with the sample `build.gradle` shown above). To create this directory, either:

- in the Project view, create it as you would any other directory
- in the Android view, just start defining a resource, and the dialog that appears will have a drop-down for the sourceset:

[image: New layout resource dialog, showing possible sourcesets]

However, as I do not know how to put Java code in a particular sourceset this way, I always work in the Project view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with build types, somewhat similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214380/how-can-i-use-different-settings-when-debugging-an-android-app/26214478#26214478). You may change resource folders in that fashion