# how to use setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG) correctly?

Tags: android, firebase

In some samples of code BuildConfig.DEBUG equals true,
but in my project that one equals false. Why is it happening? 
Unfortunately i didn't find anything about that in Google Firebase official site documentation.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BuildConfig.DEBUG` (in addition to everything in the BuildConfig class) is set by the Android build tools at the time your project is built.  It's assigned true when it's a debug build, false for release builds.  This value has nothing to do with Firebase or its SDKs.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855834/when-does-adt-set-buildconfig-debug-to-false).

Comment: If i understand right, every developer has to edit(or configure) the BuildConfig class in accordance with his own project's requirements. Right?

Comment: No, it's automatically generated for you by the build tools.